# make html page's content's height adjust with iframe's height

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, window-resize

I have a html page which I am pulling in through an iframe to another page. The iframe adjusts its height based on the window screen size height. But the content inside the iframe does not resize to fit within iframe. How can I make the html content inside the iframe resize with iframe size height based on window height?

Here is my HTML in my Index.html:

```
<a class="desktopViewOnly" id="modalPopupDesktop" data-src="Int_Sim.html" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;">
   <img src="images/images/device.png">
</a>
```

Here is the CSS in my Index.html:

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content {
   width: 100vw!important;
   height: 100vh!important;
   max-width: 880px!important;
   max-height: 580px!important;
   margin: 0;
   border-radius: 50px;
}
.fancybox-error,
.fancybox-iframe {
   border-radius: 37px;
   max-width: 880px;
   max-height: 580px;
}

.fancybox-close-small {
   background: #000!important;
}
```

Here is the JS for resizing in my Int_Sim.html:

```
var $el = $(".simulator");
var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
var elWidth = $el.outerWidth();
var $wrapper = $(".sim-container");

var starterData = {
    size: {
        width: $wrapper.width(),
        height: $wrapper.height()
    }
}

function doResize(event, ui) {

    var scale, origin;

    scale = Math.min(
        ui.size.width / elWidth,
        ui.size.height / elHeight
    );

    $el.css({
        transform: "scale(" + scale + ")"
    });
    console.log("doResize is working!");
}
doResize(null, starterData);
```

I am not sure why this JS is not resizing my content inside the iframe.